# JOIN / MERGE several tables with same key

Tags: sql-server

I have several tables that I have joined like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableA AS A
       FULL OUTER JOIN tableB AS B
                    ON B.KEY = A.KEY
       FULL OUTER JOIN tableC AS C
                    ON C.KEY = A.KEY
       FULL OUTER JOIN tableD AS D
                    ON D.KEY = A.KEY
```

This works fine, but i sometime get separate rows where the key does not exist in all tables.

Example

```
WITH tableA([KEY], payloadColumn) AS
(
SELECT 1, 'var_A1'
), tableB([KEY], payloadColumn) AS
(
SELECT 2, 'var_B2'
), tableC([KEY], payloadColumn) AS
(
SELECT 1, 'var_C1'
), tableD([KEY], payloadColumn) AS
(
SELECT 2, 'var_D2'
)
SELECT * FROM tableA as A
FULL OUTER JOIN tableB as B ON B.[KEY] = A.[KEY]
FULL OUTER JOIN tableC as C ON C.[KEY] = A.[KEY]
FULL OUTER JOIN tableD as D ON D.[KEY] = A.[KEY]
```

Returns

```
+------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------------+
| KEY  | payloadColumn | KEY  | payloadColumn | KEY  | payloadColumn | KEY  | payloadColumn |
+------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------------+
| 1    | var_A1        | NULL | NULL          | 1    | var_C1        | NULL | NULL          |
| NULL | NULL          | 2    | var_B2        | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL          |
| NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL          | 2    | var_D2        |
+------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------------+
```

But i need them all to be in the same row in the result (not two rows for `2`). How can I do this?

Comment: Getting a `NULL` with a `FULL JOIN` means that there *isn't* a row that matches the constraints in the `JOIN`. That's the definition of a `FULL JOIN`. If you want to filter out rows without a match instead, use an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: quick thought: create a view which is a union of all non-null keys of all four tables, then use that view as the primary (`FROM`) table in your main query, and left-join the payload

Comment: @jpmc26 - that isn't what they are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's my proposed solution based on the draft in a previous version of OP, and their last edit:

```
CREATE VIEW ABCD

AS

SELECT [KEY] FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT [KEY] FROM tableB
UNION
SELECT [KEY] FROM tableC
UNION
SELECT [KEY] FROM tableD
```

Creating a view may not be an option; in this case rewrite as a CTE.
At least in this way, the execution plan will continue to use indexes (assuming `[KEY]` is a PK or indexed).

```
SELECT
  K.[KEY] as sameKey,
  A.payloadColumn,
  B.payloadColumn,
  C.payloadColumn,
  D.payloadColumn
FROM ABCD K
LEFT JOIN tableA A ON A.[KEY]=K.[KEY]
LEFT JOIN tableB B ON B.[KEY]=K.[KEY]
LEFT JOIN tableC C ON C.[KEY]=K.[KEY]
LEFT JOIN tableD D ON D.[KEY]=K.[KEY]
```

If this got your idea wrong, please elaborate.

Comment: I edited to clarify the question and the non key column  (not necessary in a minimal example) got lost along the way. Now added back in.So your answer should be in synch with it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `COALESCE`

```
WITH tableA([KEY], payloadColumn)
     AS (SELECT 1,
                'var_A1'),
     tableB([KEY], payloadColumn)
     AS (SELECT 2,
                'var_B2'),
     tableC([KEY], payloadColumn)
     AS (SELECT 1,
                'var_C1'),
     tableD([KEY], payloadColumn)
     AS (SELECT 2,
                'var_D2')
SELECT COALESCE(A.[KEY], B.[KEY], C.[KEY], D.[KEY]) AS [KEY],
       A.payloadColumn,
       B.payloadColumn,
       C.payloadColumn,
       D.payloadColumn
FROM   tableA AS A
       FULL OUTER JOIN tableB AS B
                    ON B.[KEY] = A.[KEY]
       FULL OUTER JOIN tableC AS C
                    ON C.[KEY] = COALESCE(A.[KEY], B.[KEY])
       FULL OUTER JOIN tableD AS D
                    ON D.[KEY] = COALESCE(A.[KEY], B.[KEY], C.[KEY]);
```

Returns

```
+-----+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| KEY | payloadColumn | payloadColumn | payloadColumn | payloadColumn |
+-----+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|   1 | var_A1        | NULL          | var_C1        | NULL          |
|   2 | NULL          | var_B2        | NULL          | var_D2        |
+-----+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

If all the tables have a covering index on `[KEY] INCLUDE (payloadColumn)` the execution plan for this can just chain together merge joins.

[image]